# Print from Mobile safari web app

Tags: printing, mobile-safari, ios-4.2, iphone-standalone-web-app

Mobile safari for ios4.2 allow printing via air print. Is it possible to do the same via a web app using javascript i.e window.print(); ? I run my webapp using the follow meta tags.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a normal webpage, `window.print();` will indeed invoke the printing dialog.

Unfortunately it seems that when a webpage is run in the fullscreen webapp mode, `window.print();` has no effect (as of iOS 4.2.6). Obviously this could change in the future.

Comment: window.print(); works in iOS 7 when the web page is running in fullscreen/standalone mode.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that as of iOS 5.0     window.print(); now allows for printing via AirPrint.